# Get.snackbar how to only show the snackbar once

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

## this is the code

the snackbar shows everytime the user clicks on the card i want to show only once so the user can't spam click it and show snack bar multiple times

```
  Get.snackbar(
        'sorry',
        'you missed the game',
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        titleText: Text(
          'sorry',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        messageText: Text(
          'you missed the game',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColor.colorPrimary,
        borderRadius: 20,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        maxWidth: 500,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        borderColor: Colors.white,
        borderWidth: 3,
      );
```

i want the snackbar to only show one time and show again on the card

Answer (score 3):

There is another way like,

Getx provides the getters like

> Get.isSnackbarOpen

it returns a true or false based on the snack bar shown on the screen for a duration of time.

So you can do something like this,

```
 if (!Get.isSnackbarOpen) {
    //Show the snackbar
  }
```

**Bonus answer**:

we can reduce the snack bar height by giving the messageText property an empty container or size box, it ignores the default message property.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bool variable and check before user click on that button.

Eg:

```
bool isSnackbarTapped = false;
```

//On button Tapped

```
if(!isSnackbarTapped){
       isSnackbarTapped = true;
      //Display Snackbar.
   }
```

Comment: so when the snackbar is tapped that's where to show the snackbar right?

Comment: Yes, you need to change when snackbar tapped.